# How start alfresco work flow without any form?

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I have already removed `activiti:formKey` from

```
<process id="MyStart" isClosed="false" isExecutable="true" name="myName" processType="None">
```

Form actually is not displayed, but there is a box with ~10 pixel height and `required fields` asterics. So it seem that form exists but without field. So how properly remove form from start event in alfresco?

Comment: Well AFAIK alfresco share UI is configured in a way that it expect to have form for all those workflow which you try to trigger using share. Unless you customize that dialog I do not think you can get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

there are actually a number of ways to start a process instance.
If the process engine is embedded in an application (as most are) then you can kick off a process instance on deployment or using the Java API.
You can start a process instance using the Rest API if you have that module included, you can use a message start event to start an instance based on an incoming message or a timer start event to start an instance based on a schedule.

Perhaps I'm not fully understanding your scenario. But there are many, many ways to start a process instance in Activiti.